# What does "channel someone's voices" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I’ve found that I can repeat participant quotes and “channel” their
>   voices years after a research session is over.

I found the definition below for the verb [Channel](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/channel):

> to allow a spirit to come into your body and speak through you, or to 
>   tell people a message that you have received in this way.

But I don't know if the meaning is correct or not.

So, could you please explain it to me?

The fuller text is:

> As we complete our research, we transcribe the session in full. This
>   time-consuming effort is critical, because it embeds the participants’
>   collective voice in our heads. As we play, type, pause, and rewind our
>   recordings, we begin to quite literally think from the perspective of
>   the participant. I’ve found that I can repeat participant quotes and
>   **“channel” their voices years after a research session is over**. We
>   distribute the transcriptions into thousands of individual utterances,
>   and then we post the utterances all over our war room.

http://www.jonkolko.com/writingEmpatheticProcess.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scare quotes suggest that "channel" is being used in a figurative or extended meaning.  I do think the meaning is extended from the spiritualist sense of "allow a ghost to speak through your mouth". But instead of a literal spirit, the writer finds that she feels able to speak from another person's perspective, as a result of the careful listening that comes from making transcriptions.

She feels as if the other person is speaking through her, almost as if it was a spirit.

The scare quotes indicate that this is only a metaphor, and she doesn't really believe in ghosts.

Answer (score 1):

You stopped on the least likely definition of "to channel". The following definition is also to be found on the same page:

> to control and direct something such as money or energy towards a particular purpose

In the context of the text, although not very specific, it can be understood as:

> use their "voices" again

as in

> use the information transmitted (in the past) with their voice ( = their speech) for the purposes of the present

as if creating a conduit / channel for the information to flow from the past to  the present.